# pseudo increasing the 'resolution' of a value table

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an measurement array with 16.000 entries in the form of

```
[t] [value]
```

the problem is my data logger is too slow and i only have measurement points every second. For my simulation i need the resolution pseudo increased. So that every time step is divided by 1000 and every measured value has to be copied a 1000 times. (see figure for clarity). So I pseudo increase the resolution of my measurement file.

How do I do that efficiently(!!!) in `Python` using `numpy`. I dont want to iterate when creating an array of 16.000.000 entries.[image]

The trivial answer of just dividing my time array by 1000 is not applicable in this case.

Edit: to make it even more complicated: Other than in my picture the time-delta is NOT equidistant for every timestep.

Comment: Can you not just use the interpolate function?

Comment: Also, of the two examples which are you trying to accomplish? It's very unclear from your question. Please give an example and desired output.

Comment: Maybe for big data sizes like this, you should think about migrating some parts of the code to lower-level languages, like C...?

Comment: @yolenoyer `numpy` is going to be faster than `C` since it's straight `FORTRAN` bindings. Also, 16mm is not that large.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking, I'm guessing that you're just looking to interpolate between the values that you've already got. Good thing `numpy` has a simple built-in for this, the `interp1d` module ([docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)):

```
>>> from scipy import interpolate
>>> x = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> y = np.exp(-x / 3.0)
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)

>>> x_new = np.array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5])
>>> f(x_new)
array([ 0.61497421,  0.44064828,  0.31573829])
```

As far as the second part of your question is concerned `numpy` again has a great built-in for you! The `np.repeat` function should do exactly what you're looking for, right up through the variable time steps. The docs can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). Example below:

```
>>> values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.repeat(values, [2, 1, 2, 1])
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

Comment: This helps at one point thanks. I want to interpolate between the the timesteps. But my `[value]` is constant. So i still need the copy function for my second table.

Comment: @user69453 ah, I see. Included the answer to the second question as well.

Comment: No after having a detailed look at the answer, I can say this is not what I want. I'll give more example when I have time to.

Comment: @user69453 let me know when you do, since this solves your question as outlined.